# Appending files and folders with PSCX Write-Zip does not respect folder structure

Tags: powershell, zip, directory-structure, pscx

I just downloaded the latest version of the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) and I'm struggling to append files and folders to an existing zip file.

I'm running the PowerShell ISE to test the command, and I'm currently in my profile folder. Here is the folder structure I'm testing with:

```
- Users
  |- MyUser
     |- Tests
        |- Container.zip
        |- SomeFolder
           |- file1.txt
           |- file2.txt
```

My prompt is at the `Users\MyUser\Tests` folder, and I'm running the following line:

`dir SomeFolder | Write-Zip -OutputPath:Container.zip -Append`

When I open the updated zip file, there is a folder for each folder of my whole structure, starting at `Users`, like this:

```
- Container.zip
  |- Users
     |- MyUser
        |- Tests
           |- SomeFolder
              |- file1.txt
              |- file2.txt
```

But I want to have the `SomeFolder` directly at the root of the zip file, like this:

```
- Container.zip
  |- SomeFolder
     |- file1.txt
     |- file2.txt
```

The weird thing is that, if I remove the `-Append` switch and let the cmdlet create a new zip, it then contains the expected structure. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having a similar issue with version 2.1.1 of the PSCX Write-Zip cmdlet. When I try to append a file to an existing zip, I get an "**Extra data extended Zip64 information length is invalid**" error. (I'm using 2.1.1 because I'm writing PowerShell scripts for SQL Server 2012 agent jobs. Stuck with PowerShell 2.0) I saw in a C# forum that setting a parameter named UseZIP64 to OFF was the solution, but if that option exists in Write-Zip, it's buried in the module.

Comment: @MichaelMcCormick Nope. Last time I worked on it it was still a problem. We ended up not using it at all and relying upon the 7zip external executable. A shame really. I must say it's been a while since I've touched that code though (I'm on a different company now).